# Invalid Syntax Header Python

Tags: python, roblox

and I just need help with this code I hope someone fix it :D

```
import requests

cookie = "000"
groupid = 000

session = requests.Session()
self.session.cookies[".ROBLOSECURITY"] = cookie

session.post(
     url = "https://api.roblox.com/v1/groups/{groupId}/wall/posts".format(groupId = groupId)
     headers = {"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36"}
     data = {"body": "what you want to post"}
     allow_redirects = False
)
```

Output just say like this

```
 File "main.py", line 11
headers = {"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36"}
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you if someone help me! It's make me happy.

Comment: A dictionary should contain a key and a value. You only have a value. Try `headers = {"User-Agent": "YOURVALUE"}`, like `data`.

Comment: You're missing commas (among other errors) in your `session.post` call

Answer (score 0):

You are missing commas between the lines in `session.post`, and keys from a `dictionary`.

```
import requests

cookie = "000"
groupid = 000

session = requests.Session()
self.session.cookies[".ROBLOSECURITY"] = cookie

session.post(
     url = "https://api.roblox.com/v1/groups/{groupId}/wall/posts".format(groupId = groupId),
     headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36"},
     data = {"body": "what you want to post"},
     allow_redirects = False
)
```